# how should I install the English model of spacy on my jupyter notebook which runs on a google cloud instance?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I am trying to use the English model of spaCy in jyputer notebook (python 3) which runs on a google cloud instance. I have installed spaCy, but my problem is that I cannot install/import its English model.

I have already tried the following codes:

```
!pip3 install en_core_web_sm
!python -m spacy download en
```

and many other codes,  but none have worked and every time I got a different error. I use spacy hassle-free when I am working on my local machine, but I do not know how to install the English model on a jyputer notebook which runs on cloud. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

FYI: when trying: `!pip3 install en_core_web_sm`,
I get the following error:

```
Collecting spacy-model-en_core_web_sm
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 893, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/spacy-model-en-core-web-sm/
```

Comment: Can you include the errors you're getting as well?

Comment: I added one off the errors

Comment: `en_core_web_sm` is not a valid Python project, you won't be able to install it with `pip`. The spacy projects recommends `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` for installing the model, what happens when you run that?

Comment: I am assuming I should type that code in jupyter notebook. Having done that, I got this: 

  ```python
File "<ipython-input-3-e8a31c0c54ec>", line 1
    python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` (with the exclamation point at the beginning)

Comment: very close! It did not work at the beginning, but when I added "3" at the end of "python" it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to @Dustin Ingram. I should type in:

```
!python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

If you use python 2, drop "3" from the end of python in the command above!

You can run this within Python as in a Jupyter Notebook via:

```py
import spacy
spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_sm')
```

Comment: Works, but the other answer skips one command line task which shrinks down the code and avoids "!", check that at first.

Comment: @Yesh deserves credit for the Pythonic method above and below.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way, where you don't need to worry about using the wrong python

```py
import spacy
spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_sm')
```

Comment: This works and saves you one command line step so that it gets rid of the needed "!" since you can just run it from the imported module. Strange that i see this only by chance here, should become the new accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it is more elegant and Pythonic than the other.

Comment: I borrowed from you and edited the accepted answer.