# How to install a language model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am exploring using NLP for some machine learning projects. I normally code all of my projects using python through Anaconda using either Jupyter notebooks or PyCharm as my IDE.

I would like to start using spacy and am planning on attending a workshop on it in the near future. Two recommendations were made that I do first. Install spacy and install the `en_core_web_lg` language model. I completed the first step, just by searching for the spacy package in Anaconda environments (the conventional way) and installed it. However, as far as installing the language model, I am less familiar with how to do this to get this on my computer since it is not a traditional package.

The spacy installation website cites here: https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_lg that this language model can be installed by using:

```
INSTALLATION

$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

I am assuming that this is a command through terminal? I am not very experienced using terminal but tried typing in the above command in one of the command lines and pressed enter and nothing happened. Is this the correct way to install this model? How should I install it? Also, for pedagogical purposes, what exactly is happening when we install the model? It exists on our computer and then can be utilized for NLP in say a Jupyter notebook if called.

Sorry if these questions seem fairly basic, I am still trying to learn these new techniques. Any help, references, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to activate your environment using virtualenv or conda and install spaCy as @Aris mentioned.

To install spaCy

```
pip install -U spacy
```

To install a specific model, run the following command with the model name (for example en_core_web_lg):

```
python -m spacy download [model]
```

To load a model, use spacy.load() with the model name, a shortcut link or a path to the model data directory.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"This is a sentence.")
```

You can also import a model directly via its full name and then call its load() method with no arguments. This should also work for older models in previous versions of spaCy.

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_lg

nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
doc = nlp(u"This is a sentence.")
```

Comment: Just an added note - do you have any recommendations for tutorials or places I can learn terminal and its commands/how it works more thoroughly?

Comment: Just go through a cheat sheet initially that has basic commands. You learn by using it over time and google any flags or bits in a command you do not understand. There is no need to remember/learn any commands as such.

Answer (score 3):

You should activate the environment you made and install spacy and then install the model.

```
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

Then you will be able to load the language model. And, for the second question, you have a local installation of the downloaded model. You can use it in your scripts and your notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers,

You can also install the models using pip. This works on Python 3, but may also work on 2. You can get the wheel link to the models through github page and install using,
for example

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/de_core_news_lg-3.1.0/de_core_news_lg-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Or you can directly add the wheel link to the requirements file.

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases

Answer (score 0):

Follow [how should I install the English model of spacy on my jupyter notebook which runs on a google cloud instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56780427/11154841).

There, you will find two answers at the time of writing:

- Run `spacy.cli.download("my_language_model_name")`, which should be the better way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75863621/11154841).
- If you run into an error, try `python3 -m spacy download ...` with `python3` (Python version 3) instead of just `python` (Python version 2), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782861/11154841).

*(By the way, and of course, if you are not in a Jupyter Notebook, you do not need "!" in front.)*