# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy' even though spacy and python are in the same path

Tags: python, spacy, amazon-sagemaker

I am following the spaCy installation guideline inside my AWS SageMaker notebook

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

When I do `import spacy` I get error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

I made sure my python and spacy path are same

What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: Did you restart your kernel after installing spaCy?

Comment: @polm23 I did but same issue

Comment: If you use `import sys` like at the question linked here, is the path the same as the one `which` gives? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/bin/python: No module named spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013395/usr-bin-python-no-module-named-spacy)

Answer (score 4):

If you are installing spacy from inside the jupyter notebook, use the `%pip` syntax. That will use the pip associated with the kernel in use.

```
%pip install spacy
```

If installing from the command line, use

```
python -m pip install spacy
```

(Replace `python` with the path to the Python used in the notebook kernel.)