# en_core_web_sm not getting installed or loaded

Tags: jupyter, spacy

I have been trying to install en_core_web_sm through my prompt as well as in my jupyter  many number of times but did not work.

I have downloaded the library from git hub and placed in my env but still not able to load the  package.

If I try running python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm , I am getting this error

C:\Users\ARAVINTH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\c': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

If I try running the same in prompt , github connection failed error

Please help me to resolve this I have an assignment to complete as interview stage.

Comment: This problem sounds like its related to "python" being not recognized rather than specifically anything with SpaCy. If you just type "python --version" into the console, do you get the same error? In this case you probably need to fix your PYTHON path. For example, one common problem are missing quotation marks around the PATH in the environment variables.

Comment: For Jupyter you can also try not using python to install but rather directly using pip like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782861/18189622